# We Have Explored Every Lane

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *I am rotund and one with a barrow, 
>  Though you must take out only the first, 
>  In the name of the youngest pharoah, 
>  Otherwise, my shape is accursed. 
>  
>  I can stroll and am two with a chair, 
>  But again, you must take out the first; 
>  Though this time it comes in a pair, 
>  In which stillness cannot be coerced. 
>  
>  I will carry you and never tire, 
>  For quite a long period of time. 
>  My invention was vital like fire, 
>  And I burn, too, but never through crime. 
>  
>  As with fire comes killing of air; 
>  With a flame might come killing of wax. 
>  But for me, I may come with a spare, 
>  Though I also might leave with my tracks. 
>  
>  If you exchange only one letter, 
>  Then the answer will be much revealed; 
>  Though it must take somebody quite clever, 
>  For a similar word has been sealed.* 
>  
>  ***What am I?***

The answer is just one word. 
 Can you find it? Hopefully. 
 Every line is a clue, none excluded. 
 Each paragraph is an explanation. 
 That includes the title — every line!

---

**Edit:**

Added the word "much" to the second line in the last paragraph, namely, 
 `Then the answer will be revealed` 
 for the syllables match better when spoken, thus making the rhyme sound better too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Partial Answer**

I think you must be a

> Wheel

I am rotund and one with a barrow,

> Wheels are round, a wheelbarrow has just one wheel

Though you must take out only the first, 
In the name of the youngest pharoah,

> The first letter of Tutankhamun is 't' which, if we remove from *rotund* makes it *round* (thanks to Chris Cudmore for the suggestion in comments)

Otherwise, my shape is accursed.

I can stroll and am two with a chair,

> A wheelchair has two large wheels.

But again, you must take out the first,

> Removing the first letter gives *heel*

Though this time it comes in a pair,

> Heels on feet usually come in pairs

In which stillness cannot be coerced.

I will carry you and never tire,

> Wheels are used for transport (possible pun on the word tire)

For quite a long period of time.

> Wheels generally last a long time.

My invention was vital like fire,

> The wheel is often cited as the most important invention, it was as vital an invention as fire (pointed out by hyst329)

And I burn, too, but never through crime.

> Catherine wheel

As with fire comes killing of air; 
With a flame might come killing of wax. 
But for me, I may come with a spare,

> Spare tyre

Though I also might leave with my tracks.

> Wheels leave tracks in the dirt.

If you exchange only one letter,

> Whe**e**l $\rightarrow$ Whe**a**l

Then the answer will be revealed,

> A *wheal response* is a red or swollen mark that occurs from firm stroking of the skin.

Though it must take somebody quite clever, 
For a similar word has been sealed.

> Wheal is very similar to wheel.

Title

> **W**e **H**ave **E**xplored **E**very **L**ane

Comment: [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Gung vf pbeerpg, ohg fbzr bs gur ernfbavatf ner abg. Svefgyl, gur "pngurevar jurry" frpgvba jnf vapbeerpg (orpnhfr bs gur "pevzr" yvar); jura lbh punatr "jurry" gb "urry", guvf vf na vapbeerpg nccebnpu (urryf pbzr va cnvef, fb vg svgf gur qrgnvy, ohg vg qbrf abg rkcynva gur "fgvyyarff" yvar).  Nyfb, lbh rkpunatrq bar yrggre va gur jbeq "jurry", ohg V arire fnvq gb rkpunatr bar yrggre va gur nafjre! Gurer vf nabgure jbeq va gur evqqyr gung nyfb svgf gur qrgnvy! Tbbq wbo, gubhtu, rfcrpvnyyl sbe n cnegvny nafjre!! +1 :)$]$

Comment: Also, the paragraph under the riddle holds a clue, and so does the "riddle me this" sub-title...

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bad answer, but you can be

> tram

Explanation (*very* partial)

> The name of the youngest pharaoh - Tutankhamun (he died at age 18) begins with T, like the word *tram*. Trams can "stroll" along the rails (namely, when they are heritage transport not intended for daily transportation), have chairs (seats) and can run in pairs (multiple-unit system). Trams carry passengers and can serve for long time (20 years or more). Invention of the tram was vital for mass transit, and trams burn usually due to technical reasons (not a deliberate arson). Trams run on tracks. Finally, "riddle me" can be interpreted as "ride a tram".

Comment: [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Avpr gel! Hasbeghangryl, gung vf abg gur nafjre. Lbh qvq, ubjrire, fbyir gur pyhr uvqqra va "evqqyr zr guvf" juvpu jnf ubj vg vf fvzvyne gb "evqr", fb jryy qbar! Lbh ner abg gbb sne bss. +1 :)$]$

Comment: In case you don't know, the above comment means to copy the message inside the square brackets $[\ldots]$ and paste it in the upper box of the website, Rot13, to view a secret message. (It is just feedback. It is optional if you want to view it or not, especially if you are still working on solving the riddle, because it does spoil the answer a touch.)